# Recommended module or method for a generic map/media embed field?

Tags: 7, entities, google-maps, nodes

I'm aware of lots of modules for embedding media (especially https://www.drupal.org/project/emfield) and for embedding or generating Google Maps, but what I'd like is one general purpose field in which the user can paste any valid embed code, and it will get rendered in the page. (Possibly resized, if I can dream a little.)

Is there any good module for this? Or should I build the field myself and make a template for its display? If so, how should I configure that in Drupal 7? I know how to make a template for a field in general, but my PHP is pretty shaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in text area field seems like it would be sufficient, assuming that this field would only be accessible to trusted user types (see *"Tread with Care"* later in my post).  If you configure your filters to allow "Filtered HTML" (with embed/iframe allowed) or even "Full HTML",  users can just copy and paste embed codes to their heart's content.

Any HTML snippets that are posted will get rendered when viewed without needing any extra template code or a custom module to handle them.  A "Filtered HTML" filter *might* still strip important attributes away, but "Full HTML" will not.

There is not really a generic way I can think of that would allow you to verify (even if you felt confident about your PHP) that iframe/embed html is a Vimeo video vs a banner advertisement vs a reference to malware.  That is why there are 20 different emfield modules; the sources for each type of content all do things differently and can constantly change how they approach embedding.

Text filters are available at: `/admin/config/content/formats` (in Drupal 7) and full documentation can be found here: [Specifying the allowed formats for user input](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/filter)

### Tread with care!

Keep in mind that users will be able to post anything else they want, too.  The "Full HTML" filter offers minimal protection and even if you went with "Filtered HTML" instead of "Full HTML" and permitted `iframe` or `embed` tags you are still in potentially **dangerous** territory if this field is going to be used by just anyone in your userbase.

### Example/Demonstration

[image: Entering Youtube embed code on a Full HTML text field]
[image: The resulting embedded youtube video on a node view]

Comment: Thanks. My users are limited to the staff of an institution, so I'm not worried about malware in this case.

If a user posts code in a field with format filters on, won't it get converted (eg: &gt;)? That won't allow the embed to work properly. I could remove all formatting from the field and let them paste it as plain text, but then I would need to figure out how to call that in the template without mangling the text.

Comment: Using the Full HTML filter will allow you to copy-paste any embed code except maybe javascript code.  Setting the filter to Full HTML means that it will not escape valid HTML.

I have attached images to illustrate.

If you are using nice "wysiwyg" editors like TincyMCE or CKEditor, you will probably need to switch them to showing the raw code before you try pasting anything.